# What do I put for 'ALLOWED_HOSTS' in django settings when deployed using a proxy server?

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I got my React/Django website running on an AWS EC2 instance using [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/setting-up-nginx) and [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). I'm trying to do a proper deployment rather than just put up my development environment.

When I set DEBUG to False in Django's settings.py, the supervisor logs give me the error "CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False." However, every combination I've tried so far has given me errors. I know that Nginx is essentially sending every request I get through my IP to localhost on the server (right?) so I figured just having 'localhost' would work but that gives me 404 errors when trying to retrieve the static files. Then I tried using my domain (currently just my public DNS from AWS since I haven't connected the domain yet) and that gives me a 400 (Bad Request) error. Using both also gets me a 404. Then I tried the [wildcard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) ('*') since I figure Nginx is handling the traffic anyway but I STILL get a 404.

**TL;DR table**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS value               Result
-----------------------------------------------------
['localhost']                     404 (Not Found)
-----------------------------------------------------
['http://....amazonaws.com/']     400 (Bad Request)
-----------------------------------------------------
['localhost',                     404 (Not Found)
 'http://....amazonaws.com/']
-----------------------------------------------------
['*']                             404 (Not Found)
-----------------------------------------------------
all three                         404 (Not Found)
-----------------------------------------------------
['34.xxx.xx.xx']                  400 (Bad Request)
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I don't know what else to try. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '*.amazonaws.com']`.

Comment: If you're getting 404, then your site is working and there is nothing wrong with ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Comment: did you run the django server using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` in supervisor service?

Comment: Yes it's running using manage.py except I didn't specify the port in the command but it does use 8000.

Comment: @rofi93 '*.amazonaws.com' had the same effect